# Do we really need the [ie7-bug] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, tags

Okay, I'm the first to admit that IE7 has a *lot* of bugs.

But do we really need a specific [ie7-bug](/questions/tagged/ie7-bug) tag?? Really?

Apparently nearly 400 question posters think so.

Surely simply tagging with [internet-explorer-7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-7) ought to be enough? A lot of the time it's not even a bug they're having trouble with anyway, and even when it is.... well, just the fact that it's IE7 should be enough of a clue. Do we have any other "productname-bug" tags?

The irony is that a significant number of those questions don't include [internet-explorer-7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-7) or even [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) tags.

For the time being I've suggested [ie7-bug](/questions/tagged/ie7-bug) as a synonym for [internet-explorer-7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-7). Is this the right approach or should it be deleted entirely?

Comment: Yes, questions related to IE7 should most certainly be in an [tag:internet-explorer-7] tag.

Comment: I'd rather suggest internet-explore-7 as a synonym for ie7-bug... the whole thing is a great big one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approved your synonym and made a couple more, mapping [ie6-bug](/questions/tagged/ie6-bug) to [internet-explorer-6](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-6) and [safari-bug](/questions/tagged/safari-bug) to [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) respectively. I was already aware of these tags beforehand, but you can find all other tags with the "-bug" suffix by searching for `[*-bug]`.

Namely, there is also an oddly specific [ie6-ie7-bug](/questions/tagged/ie6-ie7-bug) tag, as well as a [compiler-bug](/questions/tagged/compiler-bug) tag. I have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: [tag:ie6-ie7-bug] could be retagged as [tag:ie6-bug] [tag:ie7-bug] or as [tag:internet-explorer-6] [tag:internet-explorer-7].